# HTML 5 Application Cache not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, caching, cache-manifest

I have an HTML 5 Application which should be cached by the Application Cache. In Chrome, Firefox and Safari everything is working fine but in IE 11 it won't work. The applicationCache status is 0 uncached and when the update method is called I'm getting an InvalidStateError. IE also says in the console of the developer mode "fault during analyzing the manifest file".

This is my manifest file

```
    CACHE MANIFEST

# Version: ${project.version} Build: ${jenkins.buildId}

CACHE:
index.html
files/css/style.css
files/js/script.js
SOME OTHER FILES...

NETWORK:
*
```

I can't figure out what the problem is but if there is a mistake in the manifest (which IE tells me) why does it work in Chrome, FF and Safari without any problems?

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you are viewing your website from the file system (file: protocol)

you must publish your website to a web server (IIS localhost or network server).

There are also settings in all web browsers to enable/disable appCache for different sites. (Internet Options>General tab>Browsing History>Settings>Data and App caches.

for testing purposes you must clear your appcache for localhost each time you change the manifest for the changes to take affect.